# Transfer XML via socket between server and client in java

Tags: java, xml, sockets

Hi I want to send a simple XML from server to client.

On the server side I use

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();    
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();   
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);OutputStream bos = userSocket.getOutputStream();    
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
transformer.transform(source, result);
//here bos.close();
```

On the client side i use

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

When I close the bos on the server side after the transformer, the XML  is successfully transferred. But when I don't `Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);` keeps waiting for input and my program stuck. So my question is how can I successfully transfer XML between my client and server without closing the socket. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your bos.close() to bos.flush().